# next url in django doesn't exist

Tags: django

i have successfully set the app to send me to url like

```
http://localhost:8000/log_in/?next=/task/1/
```

i have defined the context processors as following

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",

)
```

but when i login it redirects me instead to the home page, i printed the `request` in my login view and i got the `GET` is empty query set which is strande, any ideas why !?

i also tried adding

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next}}" />
```

to the login.html, but this added the next to the `POST` request as an empty parameter

**Edit 1**
The login view, and i try to print the 'next' parameter and it returns null, because the the `GET` is an empty queryset

```
def log_in(request):
    """
    This method checks for the input username(email) and password.
    If they are empty the user id redirected to the login page, else checks whether
    the user is authenticated. If the user is not found in the database, it renders the login
    page with an error_message that the email or password are invalid. Further, it checks if the user's
    account is activated, it not he is redirected back to login and notified.
    If the user is activated, it checks for the field remember_me, if it is not checked, then the
    expiry date of the session is set to when the browser is closed.
    Then the user is logged in using the login in django backends and it checks on the session
    value if it is his first time or not to open the getstrated instead of the normal profile.
    """
    print request.GET['next']
    base_login=True
    if request.POST.has_key('username') and request.POST.has_key('password'):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            error_message = "The Email/Password is incorrect."
            return render(request, 'userprofiles/registration.html', {'error_message': error_message})
        else:
            if user.is_active:
                if not request.POST.get('remember_me', False):
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)

                login(request, user)

                request.session['DEPLOYED_ADDRESS'] = settings.DEPLOYED_ADDRESS

                first_week = False
                logged_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
                if (((request.user.last_login - request.user.date_joined).days) < 8) and (logged_user.got_started == False):
                    first_week = True

                if first_week:
                    return redirect('/getting_started/', RequestContext(request))
                else:
                    return redirect('/', RequestContext(request))

            else:
                error_message = "This Email Hasn't Been Activated Yet. Please Check The Activation Mail Sent To You."
                return render(request, 'userprofiles/registration.html', {'error_message': error_message})
    else:
        RegistrationForm = get_form_class(up_settings.REGISTRATION_FORM)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']

                request.session['login'] = "first"



                # Automatically log this user in
                if up_settings.AUTO_LOGIN:

                    if up_settings.EMAIL_ONLY:
                        username = form.cleaned_data['email']

                    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                    if user is not None:
                        if user.is_active:
                            login(request, user)
                            calculate_profile_completion(request)


                return redirect(up_settings.REGISTRATION_REDIRECT)

        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()


        return render(request, 'userprofiles/registration.html', {'form': form,'base_login': base_login})
```

Comment: I would recommend using the built in login view instead of trying to write your own. If you do use your own login view, how can we help you debug it when you don't show it here?

Comment: @Alasdair i have extra scenarios more than the oridnary login, and i have added the login view,check the edit, Thanks in advance

Comment: @FadyKamal Can you try `request.REQUEST['next']`? I'm curious to see if that works.

Comment: @bvukelic actually i printed request ,and i didn't find any thing that indicates the existence of next anywhere, i tried `request.REQUEST['next']` and `request.GET.get('next','')` i just get nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to render the form, the browser makes a GET request to your Django app (this has nothing to do with `request.GET` and `request.POST`, which merely contain data sent as URL parameters or form-encoded data respectively, and are always available). Since you are using the `next` URL parameter during the GET request, you will have access to it then. However, you then proceed to render the form page as a response to the request without including `next` anywhere, so browser no longer has access to this value, nor does your app.

When the browser then proceeds to submit the form, it does so by performing a POST request. It so happens that you are using the same handler to handle this request, but it is still a separate request, and therefore, `next`, which you are not passing through the form or URL parameter, is lost.

You can fix this in the original GET request (before showing the form to the user). As soon as you receive the `next` URL parameter, you can do one of the following:

**Put it in the login form** by passing the value to the template via context, and rendering a hidden field within the form:

```
<!-- inside your FORM element -->
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
```

**Putting next in session** during GET request:

```
request.session['next'] = request.GET.get('next', '/')
```

There are more methods (e.g., adding hidden field in the login form class), but the above two are most straightforward.

Comment: i am sorry i don't get the part how to send the next parameter into the form, all i have is the url and i can't retrive it from it.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot retrieve a parameter in a GET request?

Comment: no,the next parameter dosen't exist in the `GET` request. when i tried printing the `GET` request it gave me an empty queryset

Comment: @FadyKamal: Sorry if I sound patronizing and all that, but, does that happen before or after you submit the form? Or both?

Comment: this is after submitting the html form and going to the login view i.e press login in the html

Comment: So, when you submit your form, the request is no longer a GET request, but a POST. Your view handles both GET and POST (not to be confused with `request.GET` and `request.POST` objects), and the `next` parameter is only used in the GET request. So, at that point, you have to pass the `next` value to the form. You can add `next` to the context before Django renders the form, and add a hidden field in your login form that contains the value of the next. Next time (no pun intended), you can read the value of next along with username and pw from `request.POST`.

Comment: ooh, now i see, the GET request at rendering the form but not after submitting it, Thanks for the help, Can you please edit the solution with this one so that i can accept and let others benefit from it.Many Thanks